# Define recursive notation with two recursive variables in Coq

Tags: coq

I'd like to define a notation that looks like the following for type contexts:

```
{ x1 : T1, x2 : T2, x3 : T3 }
```

However, I can't figure out a way to define such a notation recursively. My guess would be the following:

```
Notation "{ x1 : T1 , .. , xn : Tn }" := (cons (x1, T1) .. (cons (xn, Tn)) ..).
```

I get the following error: "Cannot find where the recursive pattern starts."

Is such a recursive notation possible, and if so, how can it be done?

Comment: I opened [issue #7959](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/7959) on GitHub. Let's see what happens.

Comment: It's somehow getting parsed as `{ x1 : (T1 , .. , xn) : Tn }`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coq doesn't seem to recognize `x1 : T1` and `xn : Tn` as expressions, and instead parses the notation as `{ x1 : (T1 , .. , xn) : Tn }`. This suggests to define the notation in the following two steps.

```
Section T. (* To see the effect of the notation after closing this section. *)

(* recursive list notation *)
Notation "{ x1 , .. , xn }" :=
  (cons x1 .. (cons xn nil) ..).

(* pair notation *)
Notation "x : T" := ((x, T))
(at level 100).

Definition z := { 3 : 4, 5 : 6, 7 : 8 }.

Print z.
(* z = {3 : 4, 5 : 6, 7 : 8} *)

End T.

Print z.
(* z = ((3, 4) :: (5, 6) :: (7, 8) :: nil)%list *)
```

Comment: (Fixes to disambiguate from the usual type annotation syntax are welcome! I'm not familiar enough with the level system.)

Comment: This looks like it should work. Something else I'll look into later is if there's a way to set up the scopes so that the second notation only works within the braces. Thanks!

Comment: @geppettodivacin did you have any luck using scopes to make the second notation active only within the first?

Comment: @Ricardo Custom entries are a good solution for that nowadays.

Comment: Thank you, @Li-yaoXia. That worked. The documentation for custom entries can be found here: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#custom-entries.